# SQL Server 2005 Alerts no Email Option

Tags: sql-server-2005, alerts, sql-server

I've got Database Mail set up successfully, I can send test emails, however when I go to set up an alert to be sent by email to an operator I don't have a checkbox to check to say email should be sent.

I've checked the following:

- SQL Agent Alert System has Email set up
- I've restart SQL Agent
- I have a default mail profile
- The profile is a public profile
- Operators are set up (that's where I can't see the email checkbox)
- SQL Server & Agent are running under the same account the SQLMail is set up for

I'm using SQL Server 2005 SP3, if anybody has any thoughts it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are the SQL server services running under the same account that the mail profile belongs to?  Also, do you have operators set up?  Silly question, I know, but you didn't mention it explicitly so I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SSMS, click on the plus next to Management.  From there, right-click on Database Mail, and Configure Database Mail....click Next on the Welcome Screen.  Select Manage profile security and click Next.  Are there any profiles listed here?  Are any of them set to use the default profile?  If not, set it to yes and try again.

A good resource for stepping through and setting database email up can be found [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1100).

**Edited to add**

Based on your comments below you should patch SSMS in addition to SQL Server.

Comment: I have this option enabled in Database Mail but not SQL Mail. I assume I only need it in Database Mail as SQL Mail is deprecated and Alerts aren't?

Comment: I just checked out the link. When I open up profile security I don't have a checkbox to say whether a profile is public or not....

Comment: Rather than trying to troubleshoot what you have and haven't done, I would recommend stepping through my link and setting them up again.

Comment: Tried that, twice, to make sure I didn't miss anything first time.

Comment: Is your install on SP2 by chance?  There are some fixes regarding Alerts:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/921896

Comment: Nope it is SP3, sorry I should have specified that in the question.

Comment: Just completely deleted all mail accounts and profiles (for a third time). When I follow the link and click next after creating the account, there is no checkbox to select the profile as public like the image in the article. I guess here must be the problem....

Comment: It would appear I'm a complete moron. My server is patched OK, but my SSMS is not!!! When I tried on a patched server I can see the checkboxes ok. @GregD if you want to alter your answer slightly I will accept it. Thanks for your help.